# Resolve Promise After Executing Single Line Of Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a sequence of events I'm trying to align, but I don't understand how to resolve a promise after a single line of asynchronous code. In this case, I'm making an API call which resolves to an array of objects. I'm then using Object.assign() to convert the array of objects into an object of objects. Once completed, I then want to call a function which does something with that new object of objects. The conversion process takes some time, and I'm not sure how to postpone my function call until after the object has been converted. My non-functioning code is given below.

```
this.queryCodes().then(() => {
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(() => {
      // This code isn't executing.
      this.floorCodesLookup = Object.assign({}, ...this.floorCodes);
    });
  }).then((data) => {
    this.resolveCodesToDescriptions();
  });
});
```

Comment: `this.floorCodesLookup = Object.assign({}, ...this.floorCodes); this.resolveCodesToDescriptions();` and `new Promise(` is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

`resolve` should be given the result of your asynchronous operation, not the code to execute. The code you want to execute shouldn't go in the `resolve` argument, but instead in the callback you give to the promise constructor. So for your snippet:

```
this.queryCodes().then(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Put the code you want to execute here...
    // Call resolve when your work is done, and pass it the result if there is one.
    resolve(/* maybe result here */);
  }).then((data) => {
    this.resolveCodesToDescriptions();
  });
});
```

It's also worth noting that you don't need to use a promise constructor since you're already chaining off a promise to begin with. You could just:

```
this.queryCodes().then(() => {
  // Do additional work here...
  this.floorCodesLookup = Object.assign({}, ...this.floorCodes);
  return this.resolveCodesToDescriptions();
});
```

Comment: Although not needed...make sure to actually `return` the `new Promise` as well if going that route.

Answer (score 1):

`resolve()` doesn't take a callback as an argument.  It takes the resolved value as an argument.  Not sure where you got the callback notion from.  That's why the callback is never called because that's not a supported feature of `resolve()`.

Manually creating a promise inside a `.then()` handler is likely not needed and is probably an [anti-pattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/).  You don't show enough of the real code here to understand what is going on, but this is likely way more complicated than it needs to be.  From the code you show, I think you can just do this:

```
this.queryCodes().then(() => {
   this.floorCodesLookup = Object.assign({}, ...this.floorCodes);
   this.resolveCodesToDescriptions();
});
```

Comment: I think my confusion lies in the fact that I'm not sure what actually constitutes an asynchronous function. I mean, I understand the basic concepts, but it seems like I'm not getting the whole picture. For example, if I perform some huge operation on a huge array, is this a blocking code - as in, the next line will not be executed until this line has finished?

Comment: @SeanMcQuay - All asynchronous operations in node.js either accept a callback (that will be called when they are done) or they return a promise.  If a function in the node.js library doesn't offer either of those, then it is synchronous meaning nothing else will execute until its done.  So, if your huge operation on an array just calls synchronous functions, then it will be blocking.  You can't make it non-blocking unless you can rewrite it to use asynchronous operations instead.  Using promises does not "convert" synchronous code to asynchronous code.

Comment: @SeanMcQuay - You can use things like `setTimeout()` to change when something runs, but if it's synchronous code, it will still be synchronous and blocking when it runs, but it may run at a different time so it may not block your immediate operations (even though it will still block when it runs later).

Comment: @SeanMcQuay - In your code example, it appears that `this.queryCodes()` is likely a synchronous (since it returns a promise).  If you want us to help you understand it further or `this.resolveCodesToDescriptions()`, then we need to see the code for both.

Comment: I really appreciate the clarification. Recently, I started to be involved in work that actually required promises. Prior to that, most of my work with JavaScript was just DOM manipulation or data presentation, so promises were never really in my mind. Now that I started working with promises, I think I lost my mind for a bit there when considering asynchronous operation. It sort of made me rethink everything and I guess I over corrected.